# Mod_Rewrite: htaccess rule to rewrite image URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can we use Apache Mod_Rewrite inside .htaccess file to rewrite real paths of .png files only?

**Visible URL:**

> `.com/italy/region/internal/map1234.png`

> `.com/italy/country/map1234.png`

> `.com/italy/map1234.png`

**Real location of file:**

> `.com/images/map1234.png`

Note I refer to Mod_Rewrite and not a common 301 redirect.

Comment: @anubhava 

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [QSA,L]`

it works but not for sub-folders. I need to find the right syntax to refer to /images/file.png and not to ..path/images/file.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/.*
> RewriteRule ^(.*\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [QSA,L]
> ```
>
> it works but not for sub-folders.

This would have still redirected images in subfolders, but `/italy/region/internal/map1234.png` would have been redirected to `/images/italy/region/internal/map1234.png`.

To make it work for *any* subfolders then change it to read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/images/
RewriteRule /(\w+\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [L]
```

`\w+` (previously `.*`) - By excluding a slash in the captured pattern we ensure that we only capture the filename and not the entire URL-path.

The `QSA` flag is not required.

> **UPDATE:** Unfortunately this code fails (404) if I use images with dash. For example my-name.png Any idea?

Change the `\w` (any word character) in the above regex to `[\w-]` to include a hyphen. For example:

```
RewriteRule /([\w-]+\.(gif|jpg|png))$ images/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this code fails (404) if I use images with dash. For example my-name.png Any idea? @mrwhite

Comment: Change the `\w` pattern to `[\w-]` in the regex to include a hyphen. I've updated my answer.